# How to stop Timer on parent form (C#)

Tags: c#, timer

I have Timer control (and a Button) on a first form.

Idea is that when user clicks on Button, new modal window with new button is showed, with question if he wants to stop a timer when he click on modal form's button.

Can you help me how i can achieve that?

Comment: Winforms or WPF? Some source code would help to understand the question too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set the DialogResult on the form with the question according to the answer and check the result in the main dialog.

```
ConfirmationForm confirmationForm = new ConfirmationForm();

DialogResult dialogResult = confirmationForm.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
  // Stop timer here
}
```

or use a standard dialog

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to stop the timer?", "Stop timer", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  // Stop timer here
}
```

EDIT: Changed confirmationForm.Show to confirmationForm.ShowDialog.

Comment: `.Show` doesnt return a dialogResult. your first example needs a workaround, nevertheless idea is the same..

Comment: Use ShowDialog() will return the DialogResult

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property on the 2nd Form to receive the Timer of first Form :

```
    private Timer timer;
    public frmModal(Timer tmrref)
    {
        this.timer = tmrref;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then when you show the Modal Form you can pass the timer :

```
frmModal frm = new frmModal( this.timer1);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

and on button click of the modal form simply stop the timer :

```
timer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `Boolean` property in the 2nd form called `bStopTimer`

If the user pressed "Yes", set `bStopTimer` to `True`
else, `False`

When you close the child form, check `childForm.bStopTimer` and act according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Public Boolean property in the modal form.
From the main form you use a loop UNTIL the boolean value is True

```
While not MyVal = true
   ModalForm.show
End While
```

Using this method, you can also start or stop your timer from the main and the modal form.
You'll get the point :)

Greetings!